# ¿Como usar un if con expresiones regulares?

Tags: javascript

tengo este if sencillo en el si selecciono un mero menor que 7 sale una imagen y uno mayor que 7 sale otra, el caso es que quiero hacerlo con expresiones regulares pero no encuentro la manera de hacer que funcione. Aquí dejo mi código a continuación.

```
var edad = parseInt(prompt("Escribe tu edad"));

if((! (/[a-z]{0,12}$/.test(item.value)))){
    document.write("<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/88/IncredibleFamily.jpg/250px-IncredibleFamily.jpg'>");
}else{
    document.write("<img src='https://macguffin007.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/MickeyMouse.jpg'>");
}
```

Comment: Para comprobar que es menor que 7 ¿por qué usar regex y no un operador lógico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar lo que pides no harían falta expresiones regulares, sino más bien hacerlo así:

```
var edad = parseFloat(prompt("Escribe tu edad"));

    if(edad<7){
        document.write("<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/88/IncredibleFamily.jpg/250px-IncredibleFamily.jpg'>");
    }else{
        document.write("<img src='https://akns-images.eonline.com/eol_images/Entire_Site/20121016/634.mm.cm.111612.jpg?fit=around%7C634:1024&output-quality=90&crop=634:1024;center,top'>");
    }
```

Las expresiones regulares podrían servir para verificar que lo que introduce el usuario es una cadena numérica y no otra cosa, de esta forma por ejemplo:

```
if(/^([0-9])*$/.test(edad)){
    if(edad<7){
        document.write("<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/88/IncredibleFamily.jpg/250px-IncredibleFamily.jpg'>");
    }else{
        document.write("<img src='https://akns-images.eonline.com/eol_images/Entire_Site/20121016/634.mm.cm.111612.jpg?fit=around%7C634:1024&output-quality=90&crop=634:1024;center,top'>");
    }
}else{
    alert('Por favor ingresa una edad válida.')
}
```

Por cierto, será mejor si utilizas `parseFloat()` en vez de `parseInt()`, ya que `parseFloat()` trabaja directamente con números en base decimal.

Comment: Muchas gracias.